# How to reverse hashmap compression (index method) (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, indexof

I have been working on compressing and uncompressing texts via the following method (for uncompression). Firstly, get the compressed file (e.g. "see[2, 4, 5],sea[0, 1, 3]," (the word is listed and then the indexes of the word are also listed). From here, the code is then re-created using the word and the indexes.

Unfortunately, my code does not currently work. Here is the code for the compression method which I will be putting the uncompression method in: https://pastebin.com/gqWH0x0K

I believe it is something to do with how I have formatted my code. My code uses the word and is followed by the indexes of that word in squared brackets. The current code is shown below.

**Code (not currently working)**

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String compressedString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("compressedstring.txt")));
        int[] compressedStringIndices = Arrays.stream(compressedString.split(","))
                .map(String::trim).mapInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

        for (int value : compressedStringIndices) {
            for (Map.entry<String, Integer> {
                if (entry.getValue() == value) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getht());
                }
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

I am not entirely sure what I have done wrong, maybe I am using the wrong method. If anyone has some good ideas/answers please let me know, I am really desperate for a solution as soon as possible!

Comment: anyone got any ideas yet?

Comment: That code doesn't appear to compile. What is the mapInt method? Is it the mapToInt method?  The second for loop isn't syntactically correct. What are you iterating over there?  If compressedString is supposed to be in the format you specified, then the commas are not delimiting integers but are delimiting words followed by square bracketed comma delimited integers.  Advice: do one step at a time. See if you can get from the compressedString to a list of words with their bracketed indexes. From there, extract the indexes. Next, do something with them.

Comment: it's not the only syntax error and this code apparently does not parse the compressed text - I can not see where it is reading the words...